# Are there limitations for downstream message in firebase FCM?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an android app that relies on realtime notifications using Firebase FCM.

I know that there are many limitations for upstream messaging using FCM, but I don't know if some sort of limitations exists for downstream messages (e.g. the number of requests per day)

Thank's in advance for the replies.

Answer (score 2):

The use of Firebase Cloud Messaging is free and unlimited. There is no documented limit to the number of messages you can send per day.

There *are* limits in place to prevent abuse of the service, but those are not documented. If you think you are hitting such a limit and have a valid use-case, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.